# Поиск описания параметра команды в man

Tags: linux, man

Предположим, что я хочу узнать назначение параметра `-s` команды `curl`. 
Я выполняю `man curl`. 
Далее мне нужно найти секцию параметра `-s`, она начинается примерно так:

```
   -s, --silent
          Silent  or  quiet  mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.  Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask
          for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect it.
```

Какой наиболее удобный способ прокрутить справочную страницу до нужной мне секции?

---

Все способы, которыми я пользуюсь сейчас, основаны на поиске строк вроде `-s`, `-s,` и других. 
Поиск выполняю через <kbd>/</kbd>`ввожу искомую строку`<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Перехожу между найденными вхождениями с помощью <kbd>n</kbd> (следующее вхождение) и <kbd>N</kbd> (предыдущее вхождение). 
Вот мои способы:

1. Поискать `-s`. Чтобы добраться до искомой секции придётся нажимать <kbd>n</kbd> больше 10 раз.
2. Первый способ с добавлением пробела в конец. Не работает в данном случае, так как у параметра `-s` есть длинная версия `--silent`, поэтому в описании секции после названия параметра стоит запятая, а не пробел.
3. Первый способ с добавлением запятой в конец. В данном случае позволяет перейти к искомой секции всего за одно нажатие <kbd>n</kbd>, в общем случае может потребоваться больше нажатий, также этот способ не работает для параметров без длинной версии.

Видно, что все способы не очень удобны.

Comment: добавьте пробел в начало: ` -s`

Comment: я бы даже несколько пробелов добавил - `man -P 'less -p "     -s"' curl`

Comment: Почитайте документацию на регулярные выражения, которые понимает ваш `$PAGER` (скорее всего `less`).

Comment: Если искать через `&`, можно вывести все строки с `-s`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, если добавить два пробела в начало, то почти наверно нужная секция найдётся с первого раза. Спасибо, этот вариант очень удобный!

Comment: @0xdb, да, вроде бы достаточно двух пробелов. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

**1.** При поиске через <kbd>/</kbd> и используя регулярное выражение `-s[ ,]`  можно сделать поиск по обоим вариантам: `-s` и `--silent`:

```
  -S, --show-error
         When used with -s, --silent, it makes curl show an error message if it fails.
  -s, --silent
         See also -v, --verbose and --stderr. 
  ...
```

**2.** При поиске через <kbd>&</kbd> и

**а.** `-s` выводятся все строки, соответствующие поисковому запросу:

```
   ...
   --sasl-ir
   --service-name <name>
          Examples: --negotiate --service-name sockd would use sockd/server-name.
   -S, --show-error
          When used with -s, --silent, it makes curl show an error message if it fails.
   -s, --silent
          See also -v, --verbose and --stderr.
   --socks4 <host[:port]>
   --socks4a <host[:port]>
   --socks5-gssapi-nec 
   ...
```

**б.** `-s[ ,]` уже совсем хорошо:

```
   -S, --show-error
          When used with -s, --silent, it makes curl show an error message if it fails.
   -s, --silent
          See also -v, --verbose and -s, --silent. 
           Use -s, --silent to make curl really quiet.
```

Получается, что чем точнее составлено регулярное выражение, тем быстрее найдёте.

Comment: Спасибо, но это немножко не подходит, по крайней мере второй вариант: так я получу только те строки из секции, которые содержат `-s`. Например, в моём примере второй способ не покажет строку `Silent  or  quiet  mode. Don't show progress ...`. Первый вариант хороший, но мне кажется, что добавить два пробела в начала удобней, чем набирать `[, ]`.

Comment: Пробелы вне конкуренции ))

Comment: @zombiс, ага ))

Answer (score 1):

Нужно искать строку "  -s" (два пробела, а затем короткое имя команды).

Почти всегда нужная секция должна находиться с первого раза, иначе можно увеличить число пробелов.